# KoaJS possible to render error page in on('error') callback?

Tags: error-handling, koa

Just checking, but it seems impossible to render an error page in the error callback?

```
app.on('error', function(err) {
  this.body = "ERROR: " + err.message; // this does not do anything
});
```

It seems like the only way is to use try catch in middlewares?

```
app.use(function *(next) {
  // return this.throw('TESTING ERROR')
  try {
    yield next;
  } catch (err) {
    err.status = err.status || 500;
    err.message = err.message || 'An error occured';

    this.body = err.message;
  }
});

app.use(function *(next) {
  yield next;

  if (this.status === 404) {
    this.body = err.message;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application error event is useful for centralized error handling and logging. The context (`this`) of the event is not the same as the request context. However, it is possible that the request context will be passed to the error event if it is no longer possible to respond to the request:

> If an error in the req/res cycle and it is not possible to respond to the client, the Context instance is also passed:

```
app.on('error', function(err, ctx){  
  log.error('server error', err, ctx);  
});
```

> When an error occurs and it is still possible to respond to the client, aka no data has been written to the socket, Koa will respond appropriately with a 500 "Internal Server Error". In either case an app-level "error" is emitted for logging purposes.

[source](http://koajs.com/#application)

Using middleware is the recommended way to catch and respond to errors. According to the [Koa wiki](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling).